# Silverlight page loads insecure content from Microsoft

Tags: silverlight, google-chrome, silverlight-4.0, https

I have a website that consists mainly of a single Silverlight application. The website is configured to run over HTTPS which works great. However when the site is loaded in Chrome the warning is given that

"The page at https://testing.efilecabinet.com/ displayed insecure content from http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/1/6/5165823D-1D79-4871-8AC2-42DDDB94A5C2/PNGs/SLMedallion_ENU.png."

It seems that the SL framework is loading this image from microsoft over HTTP. Does anyone know of a way to get this to occur over HTTPS?

Comment: Where did you see this error message? I get a similar one when I click on the lock icon but it does not specify the URL for the resource that is causing the problem.

Comment: The message I posted was found in Chrome's console: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Got it fixed! I downloaded the image and included it with our website changing this line:

```
<img src="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
```

to this:

```
<img src="SLMedallion_ENU.png" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
```

Apparently this link "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" will still re-direct to a HTTP path to get the image. So downloading the image and including it directly fixed it.

Comment: Brilliant, glad to know you got this fixed with a mixture of everyone's answers :)

Comment: "Downside" is that you miss out on culture-sensitivity with this. I.e. a person coming from another culture (Norwegian, like me, say) would be served a different medallion from Microsoft, but on your site, will get the English one no matter what. A small price to pay for most, perhaps, but still worth being aware of if you go for this solution. You can test this out by changing your browser's language preference. I get the SLMedallion_NOR.png file instead of the SLMedallion_ENU.png file when I try.

Comment: Agree this is definitely the most clean and efficient way of all the answers provided here so far.

Answer (score 3):

In the page that is hosting your XAP file you will find the anchor tag with the URL to download the Silverlight runtime. You can either remove it or host a download on your own site under HTTPS.

```
<div id="silverlightControlHost">
    <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
      <param name="source" value="ClientBin/xxx.xap"/>
      <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
      <param name="background" value="white" />
      <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50826.0" />
      <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
      <param name="windowless" value="true" />
      <param name="AllowHtmlPopupWindow" value="true" />
      <param name="EnableHtmlAccess" value="true" />

      <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.50826.0" style="text-decoration:none">
              <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
      </a>
        </object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe>
    </div>
```

You can customize that whole anchor tag to pull content from your site.

Comment: Yep, you had the right idea! Downloading the image and serving from my site fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

You could change the **HTTP** to **HTTPS** links in the anchor file and that should solve the problem at hand.

```
<div id="silverlightControlHost">
<object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
  <param name="source" value="ClientBin/xxx.xap"/>
  <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
  <param name="background" value="white" />
  <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50826.0" />
  <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
  <param name="windowless" value="true" />
  <param name="AllowHtmlPopupWindow" value="true" />
  <param name="EnableHtmlAccess" value="true" />

  <a href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.50826.0" style="text-decoration:none">
          <img src="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
  </a>
    </object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: I changed all the links on the page to 'https' and hasn't made a difference.

Comment: This is strange behavior as i have just visited the page in Google Chrome, and i am not experiencing any problems at all.

Comment: Yeah, that's because I just fixed it :D

Comment: Awesome, that's great news. If you don't mind me asking, what was the problem?

Comment: Yeah check the answer I provided.

Comment: This doesn't work because for some strange reason microsoft redirect the HTTPS images to HTTP